# What is the command to find heap memory in solaris

Tags: solaris

Guys is there any command to find heap memory in Solaris.I need to write a script which fetches it's details and sends mail for every five minutes.

Comment: Heap memory in *what*?  Exactly what are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Solaris has a command called "pmap"

```
Usage :  pmap    <PID>
Usage :  pmap -x <PID>
Usage :  pmap -ax <PID>
```

You can read  `man pmap`  for the details.

Answer (score 0):

```
Jdklocation/bin/jmap -heap <ProcessID>
```